# Android application building with java and kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I build an application with core java. and recently google announce primary language as kotlin. Is that good to create the newer feature with kotlin. 
Any diff with execution time or application size if I have some code in java and some code in kotlin.

Many thanks

Comment: They are compiled to the same bytecode, and are completely interoperable, so no worries, you can use them both in the same project

Comment: thanks @Daniele any size issue

Comment: Kotlin works side by side with Java and C++ on Android, So you can use Kotlin and java in the same project and they will work together also you can Convert existing Java code to Kotlin code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin currently might be slightly slower for larger projects in terms of compilation, but probably not noticeable for smaller projects.

You will also have to bundle the bundle the Kotlin runtime and standard library with your apk which increases the size by 885KB as of Kotlin 1.1.51 according to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html. This can be mitigated using Proguard however.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin and Java are 100% interoperable so you can create the new features in kotlin and they can coexist with the old java classes.

> Kotlin is designed with Java Interoperability in mind. Existing Java
>   code can be called from Kotlin in a natural way, and Kotlin code can
>   be used from Java rather smoothly as well.

see:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html